# How do I get certificate information from p12 certificate using javascripts forge?

Tags: javascript, ssl, forge

I get p12 with

```
var p12Der = ...
var p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(p12Der);
var p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, password);
```

How do I get information from certifiacte e.g. subject name, issuer name, serial number...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

p12 structures contain "bags" of different types. One such type is a certificate bag. You can request all of the certificate bags from a p12 structure in forge like this:

```
// get bags by type
var bags = p12.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag});
// bags are key'd by bagType and each bagType key's value
// is an array of matches (in this case, certificate objects)
var cert = bags[forge.pki.oids.certBag][0];
```

Once you have a certificate object, you can `console.log` it to see what information is available. Here's a quick sampling of some certificate properties:

```
// version
cert.version;

// serial number
cert.serialNumber;

// validity
cert.validity;

// issuer
cert.issuer;
// all issuer attributes
cert.issuer.attributes;
// get, for example, common name via its short name "CN"
cert.issuer.getField('CN');

// subject
cert.subject;
// all subject attributes
cert.subject.attributes;
// get, for example, common name via its short name "CN"
cert.subject.getField('CN');
```

Comment: Something like that, I could get data then with console.log(cert["cert"]["subject"].getField("CN").value), so yes.